# How can I use CSRF protection with AJAX routes?

Tags: ajax, csrf

I have CSRF enabled on my install. I have a bunch of frontend forms so CSRF is pretty important for me. However, when I use AJAX to post to a controller action I get the following error.

```html
<div id="message" class="pane">
    <h2>Bad Request</h2>
    <p>The CSRF token could not be verified.</p>
</div>
```

Here is my AJAX that I am testing with.

```js
$(function(){
    var data = { id: 100 };
    $.post("/actions/gistClient/exampleAjax", data, function(response) {
        console.log("success", response, data);
    });
});
```

Here is my controller action

```php
public function actionExampleAjax()
{
    $this->requireAjaxRequest();
    // ... whatever your AJAX does...
    $response = array('response' => 'Round trip via AJAX!');
    $this->returnJson($response);
}
```

Is it possible to disable CSRF for certain routes? Alternatively, how would I pass CSRF through AJAX to the controller action?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Disabling the CSRF protection is probably a bad idea... it's in there for a reason. But you can easily add your CSRF data to an AJAX call, and it works very well!

The key is to **make your CSRF token name & value available in your front-end JS**. You can then pass that into your AJAX call as an additional value.

There are a few ways to push the CSRF data to the front-end, so this is simply one example:

```
{# Get CSRF token info in Twig #}
{% set csrfToken = {
    name: craft.app.config.general.csrfTokenName,
    value: craft.app.request.csrfToken,
} %}

{# Pass CSRF token through to JavaScript (via the page head) #}
{% js "window.csrfToken = #{csrfToken|json_encode|raw};" at head %}
```

Once you have the CSRF info on the front-end, simply add it to your AJAX data...

```js
$(function(){
    // Whatever data is being passed via AJAX
    const data = { id: 100 };

    // Append CSRF Token
    data[window.csrfToken.name] = window.csrfToken.value;

    // Make the AJAX call
    $.post('actions/example-controller/example-action', data, function(response) {
        console.log('success', response, data);
    });
});
```

That's it! Your AJAX call should now submit properly.

Comment: If anyone wonders (like I did) how to do that when uploading files – here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16762012/2342963

Comment: There is a section in the documentation on [Ajax](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/controller-actions.html#ajax) that provides some additional methods for working with CSRF protection!

Answer (score 10):

This is the syntax for Craft 3:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.csrfTokenName = "{{ craft.app.config.general.csrfTokenName }}";
    window.csrfTokenValue = "{{ craft.app.request.csrfToken }}";
</script>
```