# Delete plugin record via ajax

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

I have been staring [at this SE post on deleting using ajax](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6580/how-can-i-use-csrf-protection-with-ajax-routes) and it's just not clicking.

For example, I have a plugin with a list of users. Each user has a delete icon next to it.

**template**

```
....
<td class="thin"><a class="delete delete-usericon" title="Delete" role="button" data-id="{{user.id}}" data-name={{user.name}}></a></td>
....
```

To get my javascript, I am using the `init` method in my main plugin class.

**MyPlugin.php**

```
if (craft->request->isCpRequeset() && craft()->userSession->isLoggedIn())
{
    craft->template->includeJsResource('path/to/script.js');
}
```

So far, so good.

**script.js**

```
....
$('.delete-user').click(function(event){
    var data = {
        'id': event.currentTarget.dataset.id,
        'csrfToken': // this is where i'm stuck
    };

    $.ajax({
        'type': 'post',
        'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        'cache': false,
        'url': 'path/to/deleteUser',
        'data': data,
        'dataType': 'json',
         'timeout': 5000
    }).done(function(status){
        console.log(status);
    }).fail(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    })
});
....
```

**UserController.php**

```
....
actionDeleteUser() {
    $this->requireAjaxRequest();
    error_log(__FUNCTION__); // to just test im getting this far.
}
```

As you can imagine, I'm getting a `400 Bad Request The CSRF token could not be verified.`

I can put a hidden text field on my users "home page" using `{{getCsrfInput}}` and then grab that value no problem.

If I log out my `data` object, I can see it's got the correct `id` and `csrfToken` but I will still get the 400.

I'm not sure how to pass the token along with the data to the controller just yet it seems.

Thank you for your time!

**EDIT**

Well, I believe I see my error, but I'm confident there is a better way (at least I think there could be)

I wasn't passing the correct name/key.

**script.js**

```
var data = {
     'id': event.currentTarget.dataset.id,
     'CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN': $('[name="CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN"]).val()
}
```

I'm getting a 404 back now - great. I can figure that out. What i'm curious about is: Is there a better way?

I've put the `{{getCsrfInput}}` on my "home" page of my plugin that lists the users. I feel like i've just done a nice hack-job on my plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can pass in the CSRF token via JavaScript: http://buildwithcraft.com/help/csrf-protection#updating-your-javascript

Comment: HOW DID I NOT FIND THIS!? Thank you!!