# CSRF admin Login

Tags: admin, login, csrf

I'm trying to get CSRF in the craft login form. I've added the config setting ('enableCsrfProtection' => true,) and added 'name="{{ craft.config.csrfTokenName }}" value="{{ craft.request.csrfToken }}"' to the login form:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var cookieTest = 'CraftCookieTest='+Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
    document.cookie = cookieTest;
    var cookiesEnabled = document.cookie.search(cookieTest) != -1;
    if (cookiesEnabled)
    {
        document.cookie = cookieTest + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';

        document.write(
            '{%- set hasLogo = (CraftEdition >= CraftClient and craft.rebrand.isLogoUploaded ? true : false) -%}'+
            '<form id="login-form" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" name="{{ craft.config.csrfTokenName }}" value="{{ craft.request.csrfToken }}" {% if hasLogo -%}
                    {%- set logo = craft.rebrand.logo -%}
                    {%- set padding = logo.height + 30 -%}
                    class="has-logo" style="background-image: url(\'{{ logo.url }}\'); background-size: {{ logo.width }}px {{ logo.height }}px; padding-top: {{ padding }}px; margin-top: -{{ round((353+padding)/2) }}px"
                {%- endif %}>' +
                '{% if not hasLogo -%}<h1>{{ siteName }}</h1>{%- endif %}'+
                '{% set placeHolderText = (craft.config.useEmailAsUsername ? "Email"|t : "Username or Email"|t) %}' +
                '{{ forms.textField({ id: "loginName", name: "username", placeholder: placeHolderText, value: username })|e("js") }}' +

                '<div id="login-fields" class="nested-fields">' +
                    '{{ forms.passwordField({ id: "password", name: "password", placeholder: "Password"|t })|e("js") }}' +
                    '<a id="forgot-password">{{ "Forget your password?"|t }}</a>' +
                    {% if craft.config.rememberedUserSessionDuration %}
                        '{{ forms.checkboxField({ id: "rememberMe", label: "Keep me logged in"|t })|e("js") }}' +
                    {% endif %}
                '</div>' +

                '<div class="buttons">' +
                    '{# <div id="ssl-icon" class="disabled"><div class="{{ craft.request.isSecure ? "secure" : "insecure" }} icon"></div></div>#}' +
                    '<input id="submit" class="btn submit disabled" type="submit" value="{{ "Login"|t }}">' +
                    '<div id="spinner" class="spinner hidden"></div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<a id="poweredby" href="http://craftcms.com/" title="{{ "Powered by Craft CMS"|t }}"><img src="{{ resourceUrl("images/craftcms.svg") }}" /></a>'+
            '</form>'
        );

        {% if not craft.request.isMobileBrowser(true) %}
            document.getElementById("{{ (username ? 'password' : 'loginName') }}").focus();
        {% endif %}
    }
    else
    {
        document.write(
            '<div class="no-access">' +
                '<div class="pane">' +
                    '<div class="pane-body">' +
                        '<div class="notice">' +
                            '<div class="icon"></div>' +
                            '<p>{{ "Cookies must be enabled to access the Craft CMS control panel."|t }}<br>' +
                                '<a class="go nowrap" href="">{{ "See how"|t }}</a>' +
                            '</p>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>'
        );
    }
</script>
```

I believe this is all correct, but not sure how this could be tested?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the CSRF field its a hidden field not part of the form attributes.
You don't have to manually type it, craft twig comes with `{{ getCsrfInput() }}` that recreates a hidden field between the `<form></form>` tags.

```
<form method="post">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Also, that seems to be a Javascript call if you are doing Ajax you need to add those variables to the script so the action knows about them.

```
<script>
window.csrfTokenName = "{{ craft.config.csrfTokenName|e('js') }}";
window.csrfTokenValue = "{{ craft.request.csrfToken|e('js') }}";
</script>
```

Usually works for me.

Comment: Related: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6580/how-can-i-use-csrf-protection-with-ajax-routes