# Contact Form sent via Ajax with file upload returns 302 instead of 200 status code

Tags: craft3, plugin-contactform

I’m using the Contact Form plugin to submit a form that can also upload files via Ajax. The problem ist that instead of a success (`200`) I get a status code of `302`. But I receive the resulting mail properly.

Everything worked fine when I hadn’t set everything up for the file upload. I serialized the form data, expected json, success (`200`).

```
...
dataType: 'json',
data: $(this).serialize(),
...
```

But when I switched to this to enable receiving files, things went south (`302`):

```
const formData = new FormData(this.form);

$.post({
    url: '/index.php',
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,

    success: response => {
        if (response.success) {
            this.showSuccess();
        } else {
            this.showError();
        }
    },
    error: (xhr) => {
        // FIXME: This is a workaround because for some reason Craft returns a 302, even though everything works
        //        fine. See stackoverflow question here and fix if there is a solution.
        if (xhr.status === 302) {
        this.showSuccess();
        } else {
        this.showError();
        }
    }
});
```

I’m on Craft 3.0.15 and set up SMTP in Settings -> EMail. I tried it locally (using MAMP) and on my hosted server. Both give me the `302`.

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it (finally).

First part of the problem (the 302 redirect) was this missing configuration in the ajax call:

```js
$.post({
  // ...
  dataType: 'json',
  // ...
};
```

It tells the server what you expect to get back from it.

Now this was fine, but I ran into a second issue. The xhr request stalled in Safari. When that happend and I reloaded the page (causing the request to finally stop), the email was sent anyways. The reason:

Safari seems to have an issue with this:

```js
const formData = new FormData(formElement);
```

I found a hint here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8797289/2342963 that fixes the issue: appending the data manually to the `FormData` instance instead of passing the form element to the constructor.

So this is the working code:

```js
const formData = new FormData();

$.each($('input, textarea, select'), function(i, element) {
    if (element.files) {
      $.each(element.files, function(i, file) {
        formData.append(element.name, file);
      });
    } else {
      formData.append(element.name, element.value);
    }
});

$.post({
    url: '/',
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',

    success: response => {
        if (response.success) {
        // Show success
        } else {
        // Show error
        }
    },
    error: () => {
        // Show error
    }
});
```

Turns out, it wasn’t a Craft issue after all ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be this check is failing: https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form/blob/v2/src/controllers/SendController.php#L60-L62

```
if ($request->getAcceptsJson()) {
    return $this->asJson(['errors' => $submission->getErrors()]);
}
```

So it falls through to this redirect because Craft thinks it's a non-AJAX POST: https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form/blob/v2/src/controllers/SendController.php#L77

Setting your `contentType` to `application/json` instead of `false` should resolve it.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn’t done the trick, yet. Now I get a `400 Bad Request`. These are the headers: https://ibb.co/fS3R68. The response says `<pre>Bad Request: Es ist nicht möglich, Ihre Dateneingabe zu prüfen.</pre>` (It’s not possible to verify your data input). Any ideas?

Comment: Probably just need to pass CSRF data in? https://craftcms.com/support/csrf-protection#updating-your-javascript (Craft 3 syntax: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/26726/57)

Comment: I figured out that when I add `dataType: 'json'` to the jQuery.post call, the `302` error goes away. But I still need to set contentType: false. The csrf token is already part of the request (https://ibb.co/cmLw68) – even if I disabled csrf, it wouldn’t work. With `contentType: false` the form works in Chrome, but for some reason not in Safari. It looks like Safari doesn’t get a response and is pending the whole time. In both cases (with contentType set and without).