# plugins route post controller?

Tags: plugins, login, post

I am developing a custom authentication plugin for Craft 3. But I can't route to my Controller via `POST` request with my login form. Request via `GET` work

Comment: Have you a problem with Csrf? Or can you specify more precisely what's your problem.

Comment: Can you add some additional details? As your question currently stands, it's far to broad to know what the problem may be.

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is lacking in detail, here is a shot at helping you track down the issue. The fact that GET requests are working but POST requests are not, your form is likely missing a CSRF token. You can add it to your form using the following twig code:

```
<form method="post" action="">

   {{ csrfInput() }}
```

If your POST request is coming through as an AJAX request then you can create and submit a CSRF token as described in [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/6588/180).